# I see the last character of my string more than once after i string.empty it

Tags: textbox, barcode

I am writing a production program. And therefore i am working with barcodes.
I put a textbox to read the values from barcode scanner.
When the textbox length is 8 i take the value and do some work. But when i write like this:
textbox1.text=string.empty; i see the last character more than once in my textbox again.
For example i write by keyboard to the textbox 12345678 and hold my finger more than 1 second
even though i string.empty it i see on the textbox like 888888.
How can i solve this problem?

My textbox maxlength is set to 8 and my code is below.

```
enter code here
if(a<b)
{
 TSCLIB_DLL.openport("TSC TTP-244 Plus");
 TSCLIB_DLL.sendcommand("SIZE 46 mm, 15 mm");
 TSCLIB_DLL.sendcommand("DIRECTION 0,0");
 TSCLIB_DLL.sendcommand("REFERENCE 0,0");
 TSCLIB_DLL.sendcommand("OFFSET 0 mm");
 TSCLIB_DLL.sendcommand("GAP 3 mm");
 TSCLIB_DLL.sendcommand("SPEED 10");
 TSCLIB_DLL.sendcommand("SET PEEL OFF");
 TSCLIB_DLL.sendcommand("SET TEAR ON");
 TSCLIB_DLL.sendcommand("CLS");
 TSCLIB_DLL.sendcommand("CODEPAGE 1254");
 //TSCLIB_DLL.sendcommand("AUTODETECT[120,16]");
 TSCLIB_DLL.clearbuffer();
 string g = "115";
 string h = "150";
 string k = "50";
 string l = "10";
 string serialNumber = b.ToString();
 string boxNumber = lblBoxNumber.Text;
 TSCLIB_DLL.printerfont(h, l, "1", "0", "3", "3", boxNumber );
 TSCLIB_DLL.printerfont(g, k, "1", "0", "2", "2", serialNumber);
 TSCLIB_DLL.printlabel("1", "1");
 TSCLIB_DLL.closeport();
 textBox1.Text =null;
 textBox1.Focus();
 lblBoxNumber.Text = string.Empty;
 }

 if(a==b)
 {...}
 if(a>b)
 {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, since I cannot see the rest of your code I'm just going to point out that the fact that the max length is 8, and you're seeing 88888888, I SUSPECT elsewhere in the code you have something like lblBoxNumber.Text += maxLength.  Since you're holding the key down, maybe it's on a keystroke event handler???   Or else there's a serious bug in the framework.

I recommend that you find all references to that maxLength and focus on them.